# clean up the [dot] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The [dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dot) tag is for the dot program/language from [the Graphviz package](http://www.graphviz.org) for describing and plotting graphs. However, it is used incorrectly for other questions on regexes, file paths, etc.

I removed this tag from such questions (may be not from all), but my edits had be approved. I was asked to post this issue here, so other users with high rep can do the job. I have found useful to [search for `[dot] -[graphviz]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dot+-graphviz) to find irrelevant questions.

Comment: Dot is also not very descriptive. Would a rename to something like [dot-graphviz] be helpful to prevent such mistaggings from happening?

Comment: I retagged, close voted and delete voted a few. There are a few where I'm unsure what todo: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177139/how-to-draw-hypergraphs) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431216/doxygen-and-external-dot-file)

Comment: Those both look related to dot.